# set gradient colour (color) for uibutton background image iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uibutton

I have purchased the Glyphish set of icons.. but they are all dark. I was wondering if there's a way to set the PNG gradient colour when I set the image as the background of a UIButton?

I was thinking of something like when the button is disabled, it changes colour. Is there any way to replicate this functionality??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method would be to create copies of the icons you're using, and tint/modify them in your favorite image editor. Name the various images something like:

```
icon.png
icon-disabled.png
```

Then, you can set one image for each button state. In Interface Builder, just select the button and in the Inspector window you'll see a popup menu that says "Default State Configuration". The image(s) you specify here will be used for all the various button state by default. In the Background field, enter icon.png. Then select "Disabled State Configuration" from the menu and enter icon-disabled.png as the Background image. Be sure to set the menu back to Default State Configuration to avoid getting confused in future edits.

If you want to set the same programmatically, just use something like:

```
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"icon-disabled.png" forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
```

It's possible to take an image and modify it programmatically with a gradient, but unless you're doing it all the time and modifying the gradient based on user input or something, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches and time by just doing it this way.

Comment: I decided that given there were only 5 images, it was easiest to do this instead of recolouring in the colour!!

Answer (score 0):

I Have some code for the gradient... if you want simple color for different states of the button.. i. e 
selected, disabled and all.
You can create different configuration from the interface builder. 
Code which I have will give you gradient color for button but then you check the status of the button to use different gradient colors..

Answer (score 0):

Make your button backgrounds with this free app:  http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uibutton-builder/id408204223?mt=8